# M2: After updating products from code, thumbnails are not showing in catalog and on backend

Tags: magento2, import

Magento issue tracker sent me here, because they think its not a bug. so...

**Preconditions**

1. M2 v2.2.1
2. Mysql 5.7
3. PHP 7
4. Ubuntu

**Steps to reproduce**

Updated product stock and price using this code: https://pastebin.com/eytSENau

Cleared cache, reindexed

Thumbnails missing in product listing (category page) and in admin area too. Images on product_view page are visible and correct, images in product edit page in admin are also visible and correct.

Tried to re-size images from command line, reindex, refresh cache.

Still not visible

**Expected result**

Images should be generated / loaded / recognized

**Actual result**

Thumbnails on product listings are placeholders.

Color swatches and other images works, just the thumbnails not on product listings.

---

Any idea what can be the issue? It worked until i did not updated the products form code. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like using $product->save() instead of $productRepository->save($product); does not cause the issue. Hope that helps to someone.